# Razor Class Library wwwroot content access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-class-library

I have a Razor Class Library which contains some razor views, and some content within its wwwroot folder.

When I import the compiled DLL file into a .NET Core web project using Visual Studio (Add Project Reference), all works well.

However, if I attempt to load the DLL dynamically (using reflection), all seems to work apart from being able to access the content within the wwwroot folder (i.e., its not mapped to the _content/AssemblyName/ path).

I'm using the following code to import the assembly dynamically and add it as an application part:

```
Assembly PrimaryAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\RCL.dll");
AssemblyPart assemblypart = new AssemblyPart(PrimaryAssembly);
EmbeddedFileProvider fileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(PrimaryAssembly);
services.AddControllersWithViews().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => apm.ApplicationParts.Add(assemblypart));
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => options.FileProviders.Add(fileProvider));
```

I'm using .NET Core 6.0.

Any Ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Can [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=net-6.0#remarks) help you?

Comment: @TinyWang, Thanks for your help, I'd managed to import the assembly successfully, it was just getting out the embedded files that I was having problems with. I managed to do this with help from someone over on the Microsoft Q&A forums. I'll post an answer below detailing the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a solution to this problem with some help from @ZhiLv-MSFT over on the Microsoft Q&A forums.

This article explained all: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5296270/ASP-NET-Core-3-x-Dynamically-Loadable-Plugins-with

The contents of the CodeProject article solved it for me.

The important piece was creating the *ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider* (which pointed to the Assembly, and the location that the files where (in my case "wwwroot")), then appending this file provider onto the rest using a *CompositeFileProvider*.

That all seems to work brilliantly.

Comment: This is a useful response, but in general it's bad practice to just link to an article as an answer. It would be better if you copied the salient points of the CodeProject article into the answer; if that article (or CodeProject) ever go offline, it renders this answer useless.

Comment: The link to codeproject is very useful..., managed to solve my issue after reading that article.